# Confused over how i should use an observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, socket.io, rxjs

i am trying to make a chat an angular node.js real-time chat application
i am using socket.io with angular and a nodejs backend

### Server Side

```
 io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('new-message', (message) => {
    io.emit(message);

  });
});
```

### Client Side

#### service

```
private url = 'http://localhost:3000';
  private socket;
constructor( private httpClient: HttpClient ) {
    this.socket = io(this.url);
}
 public sendMessage(message:Message){
    this.socket.emit('new-message',message);
  }
 public getMessages = () => {
    return new  Observable(observer => {
        this.socket.on('new-message', (message) => {
            observer.next(message);

        });
    });
}
```

#### component

```
messages:any[]=[];
constructor(private chatService:ChatService){}
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.chatService.getMessages()
  .subscribe((message:any)=>{
    this.messages.push(message);

  })
onSubmit(){
//extracting message from the input form (not relevant i think i can add it if suggested)
this.chatService.sendMessage(tosend);
}
```

#### component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let m of messages">
 {{m.text}}
</div>
<! -- a form to send messages  -->
```

Comment: What is the issue in this ? Where are you getting the error ?

Comment: Well the messages array is always empty. The function inside the subscribe is never executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out issue was server side had to change
`io.emit(message);`
to `io.emit('new-message',message)`